# How can I solve my localhost issue on mac?

Tags: javascript, jquery, httpd.conf, yeoman

I was doing some quick Ajax experiment on my Mac. 
I have the following javascript code in my script/main.js folder.

```
'use strict';
 var button = document.getElementsByClassName('update');

button[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    worker.updateCustomer();
});

var worker = {
    updateCustomer: function(customerInfo, cb) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data/customer.json',
            type: 'POST',
        }).done(function(data) {
            log('response', data);
        }).fail(function() {
            log('failed');
        });
    }
};
```

Here is my working directory structure:

- index.html
- js/jquery.js
- js/main.js

whenever I click the button i get the following:

```
POST localhost:9000/data/customer.json 404 (Not Found)
failed
```

That being said, a few things need to be mentioned:

I used to do PHP development, so to access my projects under the `Sites/` folder I had to go to `localhost/~username/folder/file.php`.

Currently on my machine, entering `localhost` in the browser returns the following:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I looked into the httpd.conf and modified

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all  #change here
</Directory>
```

and now get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

I believe that my problem is due to the fact that accessing my localhost folder directly without adding `/~username/..` is impossible.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
POST localhost:9000/data/customer.json 404 (Not Found)
failed
```

You should know, when using HTTP request, PHP server expects to get existing file and transfer it to client (if this file has .php extension - execute script and send stdout). Also PHP allows you to do internal redirection via .htaccess file configuration. For example:

(1)`ErrorDocument 404 /path-to-file` (if requested file was not found on server)

(2)`ErrorDocument 403 /path-to-file` (if requested file was found on server but it was forbidden for direct access)

I suggest you to use the both methods. Create an .htaccess file on /data/ with this content:

```
deny from all
ErrorDocument 403 /data-manager.php
ErrorDocument 404 /data-manager.php
```

Create 'data-manager.php' right on top directory ('public-html'). And via php script you can use this:

```
<?php
  echo 'Requested url was: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 ?>
```

Comment: I do get the same result. when going to [link](http://localhost/~username/ajax_test/data-manager.php) the following is echoed to the screen: Requested url was: /~roland/ajax_test/data-manager.php

Comment: That's correct response if you are accessing 'data-manager.php'. Try to get echo response to '/data/some-file' (where you located an .htaccess file).
Did you tried to change each 'DocumentRoot' parameter to 'path to ./~username/' in httpd.conf file to remove '/~username/' name in HTTP request?

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it only redirect to 'localhost/~username/' folder when i'm in the Sites folder. I don't think that it is the case when I use grunt or a python server

Comment: The solution was to add the following to the httpd-vhosts.conf file: <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/"
    <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All 
    </Directory>
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>